# Android Tabs, Detail View on tablet

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-tabs

I'm currently designing the following 2 pane layout and I'm wondering on how to implement it.
[Link to Wireframe](https://cacoo.com/diagrams/voQ1LjZcxHZQ1Nnq-C8E8E.png)

So far, I made a two pane activity. On the left is a custom ListView fragment. On the right is a detailpane. The detail pane is what I'm having trouble implementing. I don't know how to create a tab view that doesn't use the actionbar and I'm curious if the best way is to use a ton of fragments for the detailpane or just add change the data dynaically.
 [The reason I don't want to use the action bar is that I'm using it for my Help/Refill buttons]

So what tools/tutorials/advice can anyone recommend in implementing this? 
Additional information:

- Categories or the Tabs will be based on a JSON array.
- The listview inside the tabs will be filled with items from a JSON array.

Let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently using a [FragmentTabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html) and it's just perfect!

You can have your ListFragment and a simple Fragment with your details.
And use your FragmentActivity to communicate with them.

You just need to override the [onAttach method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029548/communicate-with-a-fragment-in-a-fragmenttabhost) of your activity which is called when a Fragment is displayed.

Comment: Here's a question; how can I create fragments dynamically? Like I said; I'll have n* amount of tabs based on input from a json array coming from some server?